# Auto selected of value from options in react-select react

Tags: reactjs, react-select

## Problem Statement :

---

I am using react-select 2.4.1 for the Select dropdown.
I want to auto select the value from options array based on some condition, and that auto selected value should also get updated in the component state or vice versa.

How can I achieve that?

I have tried multiple ways, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Below is my code for the Select dropdown.

```html
<Select
  options={props.mercModeOptions}
  onChange={(evt) => setSelectedMercMode(evt.value)}
  selected={props.mercModeDefaultOpt}
/>
```

Below is the options array:

```js
props.mercModeOptions = [
  {
    value: "first", 
    label: "first"
  },
  {
    value: "second",
    label: "second"
  },
  {
    value: "third",
    label: "third"
  }
]
```

Value to be auto selected:

```js
props.mercModeDefaultOpt = {
  value: "third",
  label: "third"
};
```

Comment: value to be autoSelected at the time of rendering the Select for the first time ?

Comment: @Shyam, We can say it as a first time. it is like untill user doesn't change the value from the dropdown, it should display autoselected value. Do you have any suggestion for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have added sample [codesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-mccarthy-fekd7?file=/src/App.js) to achieve this.

We can store the default value in a variable using the useMemo hook and update the local state.

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
const dropDowonData = [
  { value: "first", label: "first" },
  { value: "second", label: "second" },
  { value: "third", label: "third" }
];
export default function App() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState();

  // This will run for only during the first render.
  const defaultSelectedValue = useMemo(() => {
    // to update the local state 
    setSelectedValue(dropDowonData[0]);
    
    return dropDowonData[0];
  }, []);

  console.log(selectedValue);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        defaultValue={defaultSelectedValue}
        value={selectedValue}
        onChange={(value) => setSelectedValue(value)}
        name="Select"
        options={dropDowonData}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```